# ItemList FindControl working for 1 item

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a LinkButton within my ItemTemplate of my ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvNotification" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbReject" OnClick="Reject_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("offerID") %>' Text="Reject" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Then in my code I have:

```
protected void Reject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lbreject = lvNotification.Items[0].FindControl("lbReject") as LinkButton;
    string c = lbreject.CommandArgument;
}
```

The ListView retrieves 4 rows correctly, and I have placed the `Eval("offerID")` and it shows an offerID for each item in the list, however when I place it as the `CommandArgument` in the LinkButton and debug it, it shows the value 1 on ever item in the ListView, I am trying to place the offerID in each LinkButton CommandArgument and be able to access it, but I cannnot do so.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are always checking the first item (0 index). You can get the LinkButton from the sender and check its command argument.

```
protected void Reject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lbreject = (LinkButton)sender;
    string c = lbreject.CommandArgument;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here actually `OnItemCommand` event of ListView can be handy. This way you can control all events from the single point:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvNotification" OnItemCommand="lvNotification_OnItemCommand" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbReject" CommandName="Reject_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("offerID") %>' Text="Reject" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

protected void lvNotification_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "Reject_Click"))//or any other event
    {
        LinkButton lbreject = (LinkButton) sender;
        string c = lbreject.CommandArgument;
    }
}
```